# Uninstalling modules, specificially ANSWERS

Tags: 7

I have uinstalled and reinstalled this module MANY times, all of the fields i have created and settings, and ADD question content are there no matter what i do.

here's the order i did

unchecked in modules section
then uninstalled, then deleted via ftp
then clear cache

everything is still there, any help is appreciated, thanks!!

signed--newbie

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a module doesn't delete its tables or content in hook_uninstall, then the content is not automatically removed when you disable the module.

You can see [here](http://drupalcode.org/project/answers.git/blob/41dac10f9c77058221427429a84e14fe4eb7d317:/answers.install) that answers *does not* clean up after itself when it is uninstalled, probably for good reason.

If you want to purge everything, you will need to delete the nodes, fields, and bundles manually at admin/content and admin/structure/types or by writing some code that uses [field_delete_field()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.crud.inc/function/field_delete_field/7) or [field_attach_delete_bundle()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.attach.inc/function/field_attach_delete_bundle/7).

Comment: this makes sense to me, thank you so much.  hopefully i can do it through admin structure as i am not a programmer :)

Comment: My pleasure, good luck :)